# How can I use base::scale() on variables together with dplyr::filter()

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to have one of the columns in a data frame scaled. But when I do so, I cannot used dplyr::filter() anymore, which is rather inconvenient. Is there an elegant way to solve this?

*MWE:*

```
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- scale(df$cyl)
dplyr::filter(df, mpg >1)
```

> Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list.
>   Problem variables: 'cyl'

Comment: Do `df$cyl <- c(scale(df$cyl))` to make it a vector rather than a matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scale()` outputs a matrix (See `help("scale")`, Section *Value*).

You get:

```
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  11 variables:
#  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  $ cyl : num [1:32, 1] -0.105 -0.105 -1.225 -0.105 1.015 ...
#   ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 6.19
#   ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 1.79
#  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
# ...
```

For probably good reason, `dplyr::filter` makes some sanity checks on the data frame passed to it, one is checking that all columns are 1d atomic vectors or lists, by far the most common cases of things one puts in columns. 
For reference, see for instance [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/765) on github.

`c()` has the convenient "side effect" of implicitly converting to vectors. For more explicit and self-describing code, maybe prefer `as.vector()`.

So `df$cyl <- c(scale(df$cyl))` instead of `df$cyl <- scale(df$cyl)` solves it.

```
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 32 obs. of  11 variables:
#  $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  $ cyl : num  -0.105 -0.105 -1.225 -0.105 1.015 ...
#  $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I would have never thought about using c() for this job.

Comment: I noticed those checks seem to be bypassed if we already have a `tibble` (as if they were more trustworthy than data frames). It would work with `df <- as_tibble(mtcars)`...